Naming difference between AltA and AltB 802.3bt pinouts
I have to test the pinouts and polarities of a PoE PSE because we are suspecting an odd behaviour. 802.3bt has a table wheren te possible and allowed pinouts are specified, but for Alternative-B, the polarity variations are called (X) and (S), while for Alternative-A they are called (MDI-X) and (MDI). See the table attached.

Could you tell me why these variations in polarities are named different from Alternative A to Alternative B? I am asking because the testing chassis (software + hardware PD emulator) uses MDI and MDI-X terms for both Alt A and Alt B, and I fear a mistake in applying the table. I couldn't find anything in the standard to answer this question.

MDI-X and MDI refer to crossing pairs 1-2 and 3-6. The distinction comes from two-pair Ethernet variants 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX. Common crossover cables cross those two pairs only.
For four-pair 1000BASE-T, additional crossing pairs 4-5 with 7-8 was devised (see clause 40.8). 1000BASE-T even works without that crossing (see 40.1.4), so cables with all pairs crossed are still uncommon. At the same time, Auto MDI-X took off and made crossover cables all but redundant.
Accordingly, MDI-X refers to only pairs 1-2 and 3-6 crossed, and X refers to pairs 4-5 and 7-8 crossed. MDI and S are the 'straight' pinouts.

Is the PoE AltA MDI/MDI-X configuration dependant on the physical's interface MDI config? for instance, a switch physical interface using MDI-X pinout must necessarily deliver poe power using AltA MDI-X polarities, or it can use either of them?

Yes - unless Auto MDI-X is in play, a switch/hub/injector/PSE has got an MDI-X pinout and all other devices PC/phone/router/PD use an MDI pinout.
